# Cannot change data I get from API, ERROR: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, api

I get some data via an **API call**

```
 getPosts(postRequest: PostRequest): void {    
    this._postService.getPosts(postRequest).subscribe(result => {    
      const postList = result as PostList
      this.posts = postList.posts    
    });    
  }
```

the **this.posts**, contain an **array of post objects**. 
That in this case look like this:

```
{
    id: 123
    rating: {
      datetime: 1496782640,
      down:0,
      hot:8061.5151856,
      id:344,
      up:2
    }
}
```

Later I want to change the item

```
  incrementVote(post: Post) {
      post.rating.up++;        
  }
```

**ERROR:**

```
main-browser.min.js:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'up' of object '[object Object]'
    at PostListComponent.incrementVote (main-browser.min.js:34)
    at PostListComponent.vote (main-browser.min.js:34)
    at Object.handleEvent (main-browser.min.js:54)
    at Object.handleEvent (main-browser.min.js:6)
    at Object.handleEvent (main-browser.min.js:7)
    at dispatchEvent (main-browser.min.js:5)
    at main-browser.min.js:5
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main-browser.min.js:21)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-browser.min.js:67)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-browser.min.js:3)
```

Why is the this.posts object read-only?

This suddenly happen seemingly without any changes to the code. I also have the same problem in another project, and then it works if I compile with --aot and not when I compile in dev mode.

How can I fix this? I need to be able to change values from the API. Why does this happen?

PS. The object is also used in the HTML, like so:

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let post of posts; let postIndex = index">
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <app-post [post]="post" [fontSize]="30"></app-post>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found the reason for the readonly property. Seems it is because of the ngrx/store library. As soon as I use

```
    this._store.dispatch({
           type: EVENT_X,
           payload: new EventPayload({
             variable: Something
           })
     });
```

The variable "Something" becomes readonly. This makes sense since it is not meant to be changed directly with ngrx/store.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try not incrementing but assigning. Such as:

```
incrementVote(post: Post) {
      let newVal = post.rating.up + 1;
      post.rating.up = newVal;        
  }
```

Maybe the `post` object has been created with one of these:

- [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Meaning that has been created as a read-only.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only) I found out that replacing the value with another object works. I'm not sure though if it can be applied in your case.

**UPDATE:**

Another solution would be to actually force the property to be *writable*, example:

```
up: {
    value: 2,
    writable: true
},
```

Comment: Still having the same problem, haven't tried adding 'writable', but cannot do that do every object..

Comment: @ganjan thinking abiut it, you could create a class `PostClass` that has X properties with `writable`. And then you just instance it, this way you won't have to do that 1000 times, just once. No?

Comment: tried setting writable too, didn't make any difference.